# How to read mails from inbox before 10 days ago using java mail?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
    try {

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
        Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
        store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "abc@ymail.com", "abcpqr");

        Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
        inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
        SimpleDateFormat myFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
        Message[] msg = inbox.getMessages();
        int totalmessages = inbox.getMessageCount();
        int unreadmessages = inbox.getUnreadMessageCount();
        System.out.println("total message" + totalmessages);
        System.out.println("total unreadmessages" + unreadmessages);
        int count, u = 0, k1 = 0;
        for (count = totalmessages - 1; k1 < unreadmessages; count--) {
            System.out.println("Details of" + (++u) + "message");
            Address[] in = msg[count].getFrom();
            k1++;
            for (Address address: in ) {
                System.out.println("FROM:" + address.toString());
            }
            String subject = msg[count].getSubject();
            System.out.println("subject is:" + subject);

            if (subject.toLowerCase().contains("rasa lsi training inquiry")) {
                System.out.println("IS SEEN : " + msg[k1].isSet(Flag.RECENT));
                if (msg[k1].isSet(Flags.Flag.RECENT)) {
                    System.out.println("Read");
                }
                msg[k1].setFlag(Flag.SEEN, true);

                Flags flags = new Flags("fetched");
                msg[count].setFlags(flags, true);
                Multipart mp = (Multipart) msg[count].getContent();
                BodyPart bp = mp.getBodyPart(1);

                String date = myFormatter.format(msg[count].getSentDate());
                System.out.println("SENT DATE:" + date);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So please explain what is not working.  What error message do you get? What happens? Otherwise this is not an answerable question.

Comment: *"How to read mails from inbox before 10 days ago using java mail?"* - It is something like the code you have written .... but unless you tell us what errors you are getting, we won't be able to help you.

Comment: Hello friends, the above code is running there is no error in the above code as i read the mails from inbox like today,yesterday but not the day before yesterday & not like 2/3 days before. so what is soultion for this. please suggest me as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println("subject is:" + subject);
```

This line of code gives `java.lang.NullPointerException` when subject is blank.

Make it `null` safe for it to complete.

```
System.out.println("subject is:" + subject == null? "":subject);
if (subject != null && subject.toLowerCase().contains("rasa lsi training inquiry")){
```

If I understood your intent of getting unread mails and checking for a subject correctly. You can simplify your code by fetching only unread mails.

```
Flags seen = new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN);
FlagTerm fetchUnreadMails = new FlagTerm(seen, false);
Message unreadMessages[] = inbox.search(fetchUnreadMails);

Calendar permittedDate = Calendar.getInstance();    
permittedDate.add(Calendar.DATE, -10);

for(Message message : unreadMessages){
    if (sendDate.after(permittedDate.getTime()) && m.getSubject() != null && m.getSubject().toLowerCase().contains("rasa lsi training inquiry")) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah but how exactly does it get emails which are dated atleast 10 days before the current date?

Comment: Yes.. from the current date...

Comment: @SSpoke OP's implementation got all messages from inbox and was iterating through them for a matching subject.
if found, prints its send date. I replaced this with unread mail fetch to save on iteration, rest all stays the same.
I have replaced the comment with the actual code snippet.

Comment: @Sridhar sorry about that yeah looks good +1.